# Updating React component upon server notification

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React. I want to implement a UI, which communicates with the server using a websocket. As far as I understand, to get data from the server and to display it I do not need Redux. I do not want a local cache, I ask everything from the server when needed. The server can send random notifications, if something changes. If the changed data is visible I want to update the UI. However, it could happen, that the UI is not displaying the changed data.
How can I handle server's notifications (check if the changed data is displayed, and if it is, then re-render)? Can this be done in React alone?

Comment: Hoping that you implemented websocket(In node/Using Amazon websocket or any other language). You can re-render your UI in react alone i.e. you subscribe to a particular event from your websocket and whenever it triggers that event you can call the api(On client side) which gives you the updated data and Update your components state/re-render the component.

Comment: You do not need `redux` to make this happen. You could just use `react`'s state to update your component's state, which then it will cause it to rerender. Use something like `socket.io` to subscribe to some event on the server, then simply update your component state when you get notified about a change